# Vue autocomplete element - problem with tracking input changes

Tags: vue.js

What I have:
autocomplete element

```
<div v-for="(user, index) in users">
    <input v-model="user.name"
           :list="users-autocomplete" @input="autocompleteUser(user.name, index)"/>
    <datalist :id="users-autocomplete">
        <option v-for="user in usersAutocomplete" v-bind:value="user.name"
                v-bind:label="user.name"></option>
    </datalist>
</div>
```

data

```
data() {
    return {
        users: [{
            name: ''
        }]

        usersAutocomplete: []
    }
},
```

method

```
async autocompleteUser(value, index) {
    let that = this
    await axios.get(//fetching data)
        .then(response => {
            that.usersAutocomplete = response.data
        })
}
```

Problem is connected to the usage flow:

1. I start typing in the input
2. `autocompleteUser()` puts some data to the `usersAutocomplete`, than to the `<datalist>`.
3. I see an autocomplete suggestion and click on it.
4. Input is **changed** with my selected suggestion
   **and** this 
   `@input="autocompleteUser(user.name, index)"` is fired again!
   So `axios` fetches data once more, `<datalist>` is refreshed again.

How can I prevent triggering `@input` after I have selected the suggestion? Now I have to click twice.

I tried to bind `@click` to the `<datalist>` or `<option>` but it didn't work.

Comment: The @input event fires synchronously every time the input value changes

Comment: @SølveTornøe I know, but I didn't found other ways yet. I need to track input changes for making API requests, an other hand I don't need to track input changes when I select value from autocomplete list

Comment: Maybe I can use some flag which'd indicate that certain input is already done with its autocomplete and there is no need to track it's changes. But anyway if I want to clear an input and retype data - I need to "activate" track again.

Comment: You could use a  [watcher](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers). Then do a check for if the input is === as the clicked element (Maybe have the clicked element stored as a flag) - Then remove the @input & move axios to watcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me now. Very thanks to [Sølve Tornøe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6178832/s%C3%B8lve-torn%C3%B8e).

I started investigation of `InputEvent`. I found one thing: when you type something in the input, `InputEvent` is triggered, there is a `inputType: insertText` inside `InputEvent` object.
When input value is changed by clicking on `<datalist>` option, there is no such field present in event object and event is actually `Event`, not `InputEvent`.

In the template we have to add event parameter to pass throught: `@input="autocompleteUser($event, user.nickname, index)"`

Than change method accordingly:

```
async autocompleteUser(e, value, index) {
    if (e.inputType !== 'insertText') {
        //input value is modified not by typing in the input
        //so we can clear our data source, used for datalist
        this.usersAutocomplete = []
        return
    }
    let that = this
    await axios.get(//fetching data)
        .then(response => {
            that.usersAutocomplete = response.data
        })
}
```

---

UPD: doesn't work in Firefox because of

```
if (e.inputType !== 'insertText') {
    this.usersAutocomplete = []
    return
}
```

UPD2: fix

```
if (e.constructor.name !== 'InputEvent') {
  this.usersAutocomplete = []
  return
}
```

Comment: Be aware that there are [multiple results of inputEvent](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_inputevent_inputtype.asp), so this simple if check might bring some bugs.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that if you do a type-check on event.data, it returns undefined if the input event gets triggered by the datalist. Why this is, I currently do not know..

So a simple but **hacky** way to fix this issue could be to return if event.data is undefined:

```
if(event.data === undefined) return;
```

I realized after my comments that you have a loop of users. Therefore a watcher will not work that well unless you do a lot of looping.

Be aware that I cannot explain this solution and I have never used dataLists, therefore i cannot guarantee this being a good solution.

EDIT: By adding some logic, you can programatically blur the input element which will result in removing the option:

```
  if(e.data === undefined) {
    const allUserNames = this.usersAutocomplete.map(user => user.name)
    if(allUserNames.includes(value))
      this.$refs.myInput[0].blur();
    return
   }
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#vue',
  data() {
      return {
          users: [{
              name: ''
          }],

          usersAutocomplete: []
      }
  },
  methods: {
    autocompleteUser(e, value, index) {
      if(e.data === undefined) {
        const allUserNames = this.usersAutocomplete.map(user => user.name)
        if(allUserNames.includes(value))
          this.$refs.myInput[0].blur();
        return
       }
      this.dummyAsync()
          .then(response => {
            console.log("autocompleteUser executed")
            this.usersAutocomplete = response
          })
    },
    dummyAsync() {
      const data = [
        {name: 'John Doe'},
        {name: 'Jane Doe'},
        {name: 'Bobby Doe'}
      ]
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(function() {
          resolve(data);
        }, 400); //Wannabe network delay
      });
    }
  }
})

Vue.config.productionTip = Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<main id="vue">
  <div v-for="(user, index) in users">
      <input v-model="user.name"
             list="usersAutocomplete"
             ref="myInput"
             @input="autocompleteUser($event, user.name, index)"
      />
      <datalist id="usersAutocomplete">
          <option v-for="user in usersAutocomplete"
                  :value="user.name"
                  :label="user.name"
          />
      </datalist>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: This is still a problem( I recorded a video https://streamable.com/pzhwf

Comment: This is such a ghetto solution. Mah god. Seems like datalist is not so well supported.

Comment: I've posted another sollution, thank you! If not your answer, I event wouldn't start to investigate that event!